# Clearing Grails Dependency Cache

Tags: maven-2, grails, dependencies

I run into some problems when trying to solve a problem I had with SNAPSHOT maven dependencies [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867064/grails-and-local-maven-dependencies).

When running `grails dependency-report`, cached dependencies get listed, more or less like this:

`acme-adapter-api by com.acme

108 kB (0 kB downloaded, 108 kB in cache)`

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867064/grails-and-local-maven-dependencies/1867755#1867755) answer suggests, you can run into trouble when updating dependencies without increasing the release number, cause the cache is not emptied and SNAPSHOT dependencies don't get refetched, as one would expect.

I looked all over the place, also in the `%HOME%\.grails` directory and under the bed ;-) but could not find anything looking like a cache.

Where is it, so I can delete it manually? Or even better, how can I get `grails compile` to clean it forcefully?

Thanks!
Raoul

P.S: I'm using **Grails 1.2M4**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know, Grails uses Ivy under the hood (and not maven). Could you check `~/.grails/ivy-cache`?

Comment: And there it is! Thanks! Still wondering though why it doesn't clean reload when referring to maven SNAPSHOTS. And yes, Grails doesn't use maven, but accesses its repos...

Comment: SNAPSHOTS should clearly be downloaded if a newer version is available in the remote repository. This is the expected behavior (at least in the maven world) and what you are describing sounds like a bug. But I don't really know Ivy (except that it uses maven dependency management system and repositories) so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: raoulsson: It's the Ivy that accesses Maven repos for increased compatability with managed dependencies - if you only use Maven for dependencies, consider at least testing Ivy out :)