# How to clear Ivy cache on Grails 1.2.5

Tags: caching, grails, ivy

Simple, is there a correct way of clearing the ivy cache on Grails 1.2.5, or is it just a matter of `rm`ing the files in `~/.ivy2/cache`? I'm expecting a `grails clean` or `grails clear-cache` but have found nothing when I search.

I'm aware of "[Clearing Grails Dependency Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867838/clearing-grails-dependency-cache)" but all it really told me was where to look (and even that was for a different version of Grails), not the proper way of clearing it.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to remove them yourself.  Nothing in grails will do it for you.