# How to make use of Grails Dependencies in your IDE

Tags: maven-2, ide, grails, dependencies, intellij-idea

So I [finally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867064/grails-and-local-maven-dependencies) got my dependencies working with Grails. Now, how can my IDE, eg IntelliJ or Eclipse, **take advantage** of it? Or do I really have to manually manage what classes my IDE knows about at *"development time"*?

If the `BuildConfig.groovy` script is setup right ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867064/grails-and-local-maven-dependencies)), you will be able to code away with vi or your favorite editor without any troubles, then run `grails compile` which will resolve and download the dependencies into the [Ivy cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867838/clearing-grails-dependency-cache/1867959#1867959) and **off you go**...

If, however, you are using an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ, you will need the dependencies at hand *while coding*. Obviously - as these animals will need them for the "real time" error detection/compilation process.

Now, while it is **certainly possible** to code with all the classes shining up in bright red all over the place that are unknown to your IDE, it is certainly **not much fun**...

The Maven support or whatever it is officially called lives happily with the pom file, no extra "jar directory" pointers needed, at least in IntelliJ. **I would like to be able to do the same with Grails dependencies**.

Currently I am defining them in the `BuildConfig.groovy` and additionally I copy/paste the current jars around on my local disk and let the IDE point to it.

Not very satisfactory, as I am working in a highly volatile project module environment with respect to code change. And this situation ports me directly into **"jar hell"**, as my "develop- and build-dependencies" easily get out of sync and I have to manage manually, that is, with my brain...

And **my brain should be busy with other stuff**...

Thanks!
Raoul

P.S: I'm currently using Grails 1.2M4 and IntelliJ 92.105. But **feel free to add answers on future versions of Grails and different, future IDEs, as the come in**...

Comment: You may have figured this out by now, but I was having the same problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774497/intellij-idea-grails-not-seeing-jar

Answer (score 10):

If you have Eclipse with Grails plugin just run:
**Grails Tools->Refresh Dependencies**
(actually I have tried this with STS).

Comment: The 'Grails Tools' section is available upon right-clicking the desired project in the 'Project Explorer' view, if anyone is having trouble finding it.

Comment: Using the "Grails Command Prompt" and "refresh-dependencies" doesn't work, because that calls grails directly instead of integrating with eclipse. I followed these instructions directly (use the context menu "Grails Tools" on the project) and all was well.

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed in the latest EAP build: 94.173 -> http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-50459#content-tab=1

Download it here: http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/IDEADEV/Maia+EAP

Grails 1.2.1 and IntelliJ Build# 93.94 (version 9.0.1) and I have the same problem.  The only way I've gotten it to work is with manually adding the libraries from my maven projects (Under ~/.ivy2/) Otherwise, download the EAP build listed above.

Further, grails integrate-with --intellij does not work.  And, in fact, leads to worse problems.  The built-in integration in IntelliJ is much better than what grails gives you.

Comment: @mike Sounds promising. I will test this ASAP. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
grails integrate-with --intellij
```

At least in 1.2.0RC1 this creates the intellij project files - but I'm not sure if the dependencies are also managed by this one.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I just downloaded 1.2.0.RC1 and IntelliJ Release 9.0. I created a project in the shell, added dependencies from maven (joda-time), created a controller that imports DateTime, compiled it. All good. Then run "grails integrate-with --intellij", creates the project files but the IDE doesn't recognize the dependencies afterwards :-/

Comment: I'm still working with IntelliJ 8.1 - this works fine. I've saw a blog post that Intellij 9 EAP has some bug fixes for Grails - maybe use that one.