# IntelliJ IDEA Grails Not Seeing Jar

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, dependencies

I'm trying to reference a class within IntelliJ IDEA 9.0.2 in a Grails project on a Linux system. I added the dependency to `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.5'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.6'
  }
```

I see the `org.apache.poi` in my `~/.ivy2/cache` directory, but get a compile error when referencing a class in the jars. In fact, the code complete doesn't show any `org.apache.poi` classes. So it appears IntelliJ doesn't know about these classes.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Why doesn't IntelliJ see these classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out...  "Tools-->Synchronize Grails dependencies"

In IntelliJ 13.1, it is now: Tools -> Grails -> Synchronize Grails

In IntelliJ 15, the "Synchronize" option moved to File -> Synchronize

Comment: Just an update to this useful answer, in IntelliJ 13.1, it is now: Tools -> Grails -> Synchronize Grails settings.

Answer (score 2):

In IntelliJ 15, the "Synchronize" option moved to File -> Synchronize