# Trying to use GPars with IntelliJ and grails

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea, dependencies, gpars

I have been having a lot of trouble using an external JAR, GPars, in an IntelliJ Grails project.  I think it is a problem with specifying the dependency.  I am using [GPars-1.0.0](http://gpars.codehaus.org/).  I saved it in the lib directory and included it as a dependency using the IntelliJ GUI-- Project Structure -> Module -> Add.  [I synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774497/intellij-idea-grails-not-seeing-jar/2774809).  I also tried [adding directly to BuildConfig.groovy](http://groovy.dzone.com/articles/concurrency-and-background):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.0.0'
}
```

I get Code Assist when typing and it compiles. But when I run the following:

```
import static groovyx.gpars.*

...

GParsPool.withPool {
     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].eachParallel { println it }
}
```

I get ClassNotFoundException Message jsr166y.ForkJoinPool for the statement "GParsePool.withPool"

```
Line | Method 
->>  156 | findClass                 in org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader
|    306 | loadClass                 in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    128 | loadClass . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader
|    247 | loadClass                 in java.lang.ClassLoader
|   2427 | privateGetDeclaredMethods in java.lang.Class
|   1791 | getDeclaredMethods        in     ''
|     46 | getLocked . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference
|     33 | get                       in     ''
|     80 | load . . . . . . . . . .  in allison.zipcode.ZipcodeService$$ENsSBrUW
|     30 | load                      in allison.zipcode.CountryController
|    195 | doFilter . . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter                  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|    886 | runTask . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|    908 | run                       in     ''
^    680 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Any ideas?  Did I specify the dependency correctly in BuildConfig?  My code example may be wrong but it seems to follow [this example](http://gpars.org/1.0.0/guide/guide/dataParallelism.html#dataParallelism_parallelCollections_GParsPool).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out: I hadn't included jsr166y.jar

```
compile "org.codehaus.jsr166-mirror:jsr166y:1.7.0"
```